# Execute two chunks of code in sequence but the code itself in parallel

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx

I have a piece of code that needs to be executed after another. For example, I have an addition `slv_reg2 <= slv_reg0 + slv_reg1;` and then I need the result subtracted from a number.

```
architecture IMP of user_logic is

signal slv_reg0                       : std_logic_vector(0 to C_SLV_DWIDTH-1); --32 bits wide
signal slv_reg1                       : std_logic_vector(0 to C_SLV_DWIDTH-1);
signal slv_reg2                       : std_logic_vector(0 to C_SLV_DWIDTH-1);
signal slv_reg3                       : std_logic_vector(0 to C_SLV_DWIDTH-1);
signal flag                           : bit := '0';

begin

  slv_reg2 <= slv_reg0 + slv_reg1;
  flag <= '1'; 

process (flag)
begin
  IF (flag = '1') THEN
    slv_reg3 <= slv_reg0 - slv_reg2;
  END IF;  
end process; 

end IMP;
```

I haven't tested the code above but I would like some feedback if my thought is correct. What is contained in the `process` doens't need to run in sequence, how can I make this part also run in parallel?

In summary, I have two chunks of code that need to be executed in sequence but the code itselft should run in parallel.

--UPDATE--

```
begin

process (flag, clk)
begin
IF (flag = '1' AND rising_edge(clk)) THEN
  slv_regX <= (slv_reg0 - slv_reg1) + (slv_reg2 - slv_reg3) +(slv_reg4 - slv_reg5); --...etc
  flag = '0';
END IF;  
end process; 

end IMP;
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest method is to remove the data dependency, so you would have

```
slv_reg2 <= slv_reg0 + slv_reg1;
slv_reg3 <= slv_reg0 - (slv_reg0 + slv_reg1);
```

in the same process.  This will run in parallel, and the adder should be reused.  Well, actually it won't in this case as the second expression should get simplified to just -slv_reg1, but with different equations you might not be able to make that simplification.

Now, if chaining these two operations in the same clock cycle is too slow, then what you can do is add a pipeline register, like so:

```
slv_reg0_delay <= slv_reg0;
slv_reg2 <= slv_reg0 + slv_reg1;
svl_reg2_delay <= slv_reg2;
slv_reg3 <= slv_reg0_delay - slv_reg2;
```

In this case, you'll get the result in slv_reg2_delay and slv_reg3 with a 2 cycle pipeline delay.

Comment: Because the data are send in sequence by a microprocessor I also need an "Enable" flag where my process would start. I added an updated codeblock. The flag is a register set to '1' by the processor to initiate the execution and the hardware is able to set it to '0' so the cpu can poll it. I'm not sure about the  `flag = '1' AND rising_edge(clk)` if it is the right statement since `flag='1'` will be executed much faster than the rest.

Comment: Perhaps I could add a `wait for clk_period` between `slv_regX` and `flag='0'`